# webdriver-manager update-config.json absolute paths

Tags: selenium, protractor, webdriver-manager

At `webdriver-manager\selenium\update-config.json` for "last" and "all" JSON parameters, I have absolute paths. How I can set relative paths to them?

I tried "..\" and ".\" but it's not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you need this? What is your use case that requires this?

Comment: test project is in svn repo. And when other testers update it, they got my paths.

Comment: So how are other testers planning to use it? Why not expose the webdriver-manager binary from your package.json?

Comment: I am encountering the same issue. The update-config.json file is very strange. It appeared after updateded my webdriver-manager and cannot be removed. I want to upload this project to our github, so anyone can use it directly after cloning this project.

Comment: The `update-config.json` is a generated temporary file and shouldn't be saved to github. I'm not sure why you would want to save that data to github. How are you planning to use this file? Its main purpose is to write the paths so Protractor can easily pick it up and launch the latest versions.

Comment: If I delete this file, an error occured when running protractor:Error: No update-config.json found. Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.

Comment: Is there any other configuration which has pointed to this file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, so this is the design of `update-config.json`, what it is used for and why it is there.

## Write update-config.json during update

When a user calls `webdriver-manager update`, the binaries are downloaded and renamed to include the version number. This allows a user to have multiple versions of a binary in their output directory. Previously around ~2015, the file would be downloaded and the uncompressed file for ChromeDriver name would just be `chromedriver` (or `chromedriver.exe` on Windows). Now, we rename to include the version. So if we downloaded version 2.28, the uncompressed file would be `chromedriver_2.28`

## How this is used by Protractor

Previously (~2015), the driver provider for `local` and `directConnect` would make assumptions on the filename. So for our previous example, it would assume that the file was `chromedriver` (or `chromedriver.exe` on Windows).

There are a couple of issues with appending a version number:

1. Protractor does not keep track of the version numbers downloaded by webdriver-manager
2. Previous assumptions worked by using the config.json for the version number; however, this did not allow a user to download custom versions.

So what happens is that we keep track of the "latest" version downloaded. The last version downloaded by webdriver-manager will be used by Protractor. The "all" field was just a list of versions downloaded. I believe when we call "status" these values are used.

Obviously, if you delete the `update-config.json` but still have the binaries, Protractor will not find the `update-config.json`. Therefore it won't be able to run `local` or `directConnect` and will complain / ask to run `webdriver-manager update`.

## Why this should not be stored in git

Previous comments ask about storing this value. The idea here is that, just like the binaries and caching files, this file is temporary and should not be stored in git. I actually do not understand the use case where a user wants to have a relative path to the `update-config.json` but if you need to reference it via code then I would do something like [lib/driverProviders/local.ts#L43](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/driverProviders/local.ts#L43).

Comment: after I deleted ``update-config.json``, protractor cannot work as you said. It still tried to find it.

Answer (score 6):

You can try to update it like this, it will definitely update it in node_modules/protractor

```
$./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
```

Comment: I don't know why this answer isn't up voted. Have been searching nearly 2 Days for a fix regarding my issue which is similar to that one and none of the provided hints also here in SO did help. This one did fix my issue.

Comment: For windows user: `node node_modules\protractor\bin\webdriver-manager update`

Comment: this one resolves my issue. thanks much :)