# Unable to use protractor with chromedriver and selenium server directly

Tags: protractor, webdriver-manager

Recently I updated my `protractor`, `webdriver-manager`, `chromedriver`, `selenium-server`.

After that I faced this problem: formerly we shared one protractor application in github with `chromedriver` and `selenium-server` in it. So others in my project can use it directly after downloaded this git project.

We don't have `seleniumAddress` and `directConnect` in our protractor configuration file. It means we launched tests with local driver.

But now `update-config.json` file was added to track chromedriver and selenium-server version and the paths in it were all absolute paths. We need to changed the paths after downloaded it.

So how can we use local driver without `update-config.json` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a long explanation of how Protractor uses the `update-config.json` in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42911197/webdriver-manager-update-config-json-absolute-paths/42964134#42964134). The good news is you could avoid the `update-config.json` if you want to. I'll provide both examples for the `local` and `directConnect` since these are similar:

## local without update-config.json

In `lib/driverProviders/local.ts`, the `update-config.json` could be avoided if you provide the paths to [`chromeDriver`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/driverProviders/local.ts#L60) and the [`seleniumServerJar`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/driverProviders/local.ts#L38) in your config file. If Protractor cannot find them, it will throw a `BrowserError`.

So your configuration file would look something like:

```
exports.config = {
  // launch locally when fields directConnect and seleniumAddress are not provided
  chromeDriver: '/path/to/chromedriver',
  seleniumServerJar: '/path/to/seleniumStandaloneServer.jar',
  specs: [ '/some/test.js' ],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  }
}
```

## directConnect without update-config.json

Similarly, if you provide the [`chromeDriver`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/driverProviders/direct.ts#L62) path when using `directConnect` in your config, you could avoid using the `update-config.json`. The configuration file will look something like:

```
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,
  chromeDriver: '/path/to/chromedriver',
  specs: [ '/some/test.js' ],
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  }
}
```

Comment: OK, it works. But why do you add the full absolute path to update-config.json, not just the version?

Comment: Yes, it takes a path and verifies the path works. https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/driverProviders/local.ts#L78. The version is not enough because the file could be anywhere. If it was a local path that could resolve, then you should use the `update-config.json`

Comment: This appears to be off topic from the question... however, in my opinion, you'll need to do your own research about the pro's and con's of the tools you decide to use.

Comment: @cnishina : Okay. I am removing the same. It would have been good to hear only the pro's of Protractor.