# "Cannot set property 'msg' of null" error when running “webdriver-manager update”

Tags: protractor, webdriver-manager

Operating System: Windows7 x64

npm:3.10.10

webdriver-manager:12.0.5

protractor:5.1.1

nodejs:6.10.0

Error info:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm>webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl
[14:34:48] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
[14:34:48] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
[14:34:48] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
[14:34:52] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
[14:34:53] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
[14:35:06] I/http_utils - ignoring SSL certificate
[14:35:57] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.29.zip
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\lib\files\downloader.js:53
                                    error.msg = 'Error: corrupt download for ' + fileName +
                                              ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'msg' of null
    at fs.stat (C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\built\lib\files\downloader.js:53:47)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)
```

It's ok yesterday and I think this error is caused by the new webdriver-manager 12.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webdriver-manager@12.0.5 did not change the way the files were downloaded. The only new thing is that it does not download a new cache on `webdriver-manager start`. What could be the problem is that you might have cancelled the job when the file was writing the cached response.

You could do is navigate to your `webdriver-manager/selenium/` folder and delete the contents or just delete the entire `selenium/` directory then retry `webdriver-manager update --ignore_ssl`

Comment: Also, not really part of the answer, but could you check to see the file size of the response json and xml files if the are size 0?

Comment: It works fine today. It seems the problem is caused by geckodriver-v0.16.1.zip. This zip file is broken yesterday and cannot be unzipped.

Comment: Actually, these days I asked so many questions, because I want to upload newest protractor which is installed with chromedriver and selenium-server-jar to our private  npm registry, so other guys in my team can get protractor with npm install after set dependencies in package.json. But we have a problem, users need to changed the paths in update-config.json file manually after npm install. I have wrote a Windows batch script to modify update-config.json file and set system variable and put this file in protractor module. But how can this script run automatically when npm install?

Comment: As I know, when `npm install -g protractor`, protractor will be download and the system variable is set. How do you make this happen?

Comment: @ cnishina can you have a look at this?

Comment: Oh, well did you know there are ways to not use update-config.json at all? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43581462/unable-to-use-protractor-with-chromedriver-and-selenium-server-directly/43583194#43583194. I would create a different stackoverflow question. Also, add more information about this set up and add why you are doing this.